# R: how to specify confidence intervals in metaprop of package meta

Tags: r, statistics

```
library(meta)
event <- c(81, 15, 0, 1)
n <- c(263, 148, 20, 29)
#
m1 <- metaprop(event, n, sm="PLOGIT", method.ci="SA")
```

I'm interested in combining proportions in a meta-analysis. In the above example, I have 4 studies, each reporting a proportion. And it appears that `metaprop` calculates CIs for each of the 4 studies. However, since the 4 studies already report CI (in the original paper), is there a way to incorporate the actual, reported CIs into the meta-analysis calculations instead of having `metaprop` calculate them on its own?

I am also open to exploring other packages if they will allow me to specify the CIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, keep in mind that you might be making a huge mistake. I don't see a reason not to take the CI from the `metaprop` function. You should take the calculated CIs from the package, specially if you are using the random-effects model. The mean individual effects and CIs will be calculated differently from the fixed-effect one. Anyways, here it is:

You can find the lower confidence limits in:

```
> m1$lower
[1] 0.25219013 0.05273001 0.00000000 0.00000000
```

And the upper confidence limits in:

```
> m1$upper
[1] 0.3637795 0.1499727 0.0000000 0.1008922
```

You can also access the individual mean effects in `TE`:

```
> m1$TE
[1] -0.8095575 -2.1822989 -3.7135721 -3.3322045
```

Then, you could manually add your own calculated values in these vectors, and they will appear in your forest plot.

Let's say your own lower values are `myLCL`:

```
myLCL <- seq(-1, -.25, .25) # define lower confidence limits

m1$lower <- myLCL # assign them to the respective location
m1$lower
[1] -1.00 -0.75 -0.50 -0.25
```

And your upper confidence limits are `myUCL`:

```
myUCL <- seq(.25, 1, .25) # define upper confidence limits

m1$upper <- myUCL # assign them to the respective location
m1$upper
[1] 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "You should take the calculated CIs from the package, specially if you are using the random-effects model. "? The reason I wanted to use the original CIs (reported from the paper) is that the CIs represent a measure of variability around the estimate. I wanted the metaprop function to take into account the actual variability in the studies. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh now I see what you mean... I am sorry, I completely misunderstood your question. I don't think this is possible to do, either using the meta or metafor package... So I wonder if you should be doing it at all?